# How-to disable right mouse click for Adobe Flex WebApp

Tags: flash, flex3

Say, I've an Adobe Flex 3.0 WebUI App. I'd like to limit the user only to those operations that I programmed myself. As such, I'd like to disable right mouse click.

Is it at all possible? If so, how can this be done?

Thanks in advance.